# Management of subscription using Stripe Webhooks

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks, prisma

I want to gather some knowledge in this post about best practices and how to use stripe webhooks properly when managing subscriptions/plans.

Looking around, I couldn't find any concrete example of how to do this correctly, so my example isn't really tested. I would really appreciate your opinion on it or maybe to point a mistake that would make my webhook fail when in production.

In my implementation, I have three different plans: basic, premium and beyond. This is my implementation of the endpoint using Next.js API Routes.

/api/stripe/webhook.ts

```js
enum WebhookEvent {
    SubscriptionCreated = 'customer.subscription.created',
    SubscriptionUpdated = 'customer.subscription.updated',
    SubscriptionDeleted = 'customer.subscription.deleted',
    InvoiceCreated = 'invoice.created',
    InvoiceFinalized = 'invoice.finalized',
    InvoicePaid = 'invoice.paid',
    PaymentFailed = 'invoice.payment_failed',
}

const handler: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    if (!sig) return res.status(400).end();

    try {
        const payload = await buffer(req);
        const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            payload,
            sig,
            process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SIGNING_SECRET as string
        );

        switch (event.type) {
            case WebhookEvent.SubscriptionCreated:
            case WebhookEvent.SubscriptionUpdated: {
                const sub = event.data.object as Stripe.Subscription;
                const product = await stripe.products.retrieve(sub.items.data[0].price.product as string);
                const plan = product.metadata.plan as Plan;

                const user = await prisma.user.update({
                    where: { customerId: sub.customer as string },
                    data: {
                        priceId: sub.items.data[0].price.id,
                        plan,
                        subscriptionStatus: sub.status as SubscriptionStatus,
                    },
                    select: { alias: true, email: true },
                });

                console.log(
                    `${user.alias} (${user.email}) has updated their subscription.
                    Suscription status: ${sub.status}
                    Subscription Plan: ${plan}`
                );
                return res.status(200).end();
            }
            case WebhookEvent.SubscriptionDeleted: {
                const sub = event.data.object as Stripe.Subscription;
                const user = await prisma.user.update({
                    where: { customerId: sub.customer as string },
                    data: {
                        plan: 'free',
                        priceId: null,
                        subscriptionPeriodStart: null,
                        subscriptionPeriodEnd: null,
                        subscriptionStatus: 'active',
                    },
                    select: { alias: true, email: true },
                });
                console.log(
                    `${user.alias} (${user.email}) has deleted their subscription. Suscription status: ${sub.status}`
                );
                //TODO: Send the user an e-mail saying goodbye.
                return res.status(200).end();
            }
            case WebhookEvent.InvoiceCreated: {
                console.log('An invoice has been created. Returning status 200 to Stripe...');
                return res.status(200).end();
            }
            case WebhookEvent.InvoiceFinalized: {
                console.log('An invoice has been finalized. Sending e-mail to user...');
                //TODO: send invoice to user's e-mail.
                return res.status(200).end();
            }
            case WebhookEvent.InvoicePaid: {
                const invoice = event.data.object as Stripe.Invoice;
                const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(invoice.subscription as string);
                const user = await prisma.user.update({
                    where: { customerId: invoice.customer as string },
                    data: {
                        subscriptionStatus: subscription.status as SubscriptionStatus,
                        subscriptionPeriodStart: subscription.current_period_start,
                        subscriptionPeriodEnd: subscription.current_period_end,
                    },
                    select: { alias: true, email: true },
                });
                console.log(
                    `${user.alias} (${user.email}) has paid their invoice!
                    Suscription status: ${subscription.status}
                    Start date: ${new Date(invoice.period_start * 1000).toISOString()}
                    End date: ${new Date(invoice.period_end * 1000).toISOString()}`
                );
                return res.status(200).end();
            }
            case WebhookEvent.PaymentFailed: {
                const invoice = event.data.object as Stripe.Invoice;
                const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(invoice.subscription as string);
                const user = await prisma.user.update({
                    where: { customerId: invoice.customer as string },
                    data: { subscriptionStatus: subscription.status as SubscriptionStatus },
                    select: { alias: true, email: true },
                });
                console.log(
                    `${user.alias} (${user.email}) has failed to pay an invoice. Suscription status: ${subscription.status}`
                );
                //TODO: Send the user an e-mail noticing this fail.
                return res.status(200).end();
            }
            default:
                res.status(404).end();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(400).send('Webhook Error');
    }
};

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

export default handler;
```

Are there any problems with this implementation? Is it production-ready? What could be made better?

Comment: No one can say it's production-ready without knowing what are concrete goals of your system. With a first glance it looks ok but it really depends on your business logic. Make sure to reference Stripe Docs general advices for Subscription webhook: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks